# How to answer a negative question in English?

Tags: questions, negation, responses, multiple-negation

> Q: "Don't you know?"

If I really don't know, how should I respond to this question? *Yes* or *No*?

There's a similar question on EL&U, but the answer isn't clear how it works:

- [A confusion about answer yes and no to some complicated question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281663/a-confusion-about-answer-yes-and-no-to-some-complicated-question)

Also here on ELU too:

- [how-to-answer-a-negative-question-without-ambiguity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28530/how-to-answer-a-negative-question-without-ambiguity)

These answers are confusing. I want to know what one word answer I can use. In other words I want to know:

- What will native speakers understand if I reply *No* to this question?
- What will native speakers understand if I reply *Yes* to this question?

Comment: **"No, I don't."** would be ideal

Comment: Can't it be answered with only Yes or No? Again similar question:)

Comment: If the conversation is **informal**, yes, short 'no' works. But don't prefer that though.

Comment: Answering yes or no by itself can be misinterpreted. It is always better to add confirmation "I do/I don't".

Comment: How about asking 'what' as an answer for something that you don't know. :)

Comment: Just look up in the sky/ceiling, and they will know. I agree with @user3169 You can say: **No, I don't know."**

Comment: @RuchirM asking "what" might make the asker repeat his/her question. :)

Comment: @MaulikV I don't think the OP's concerns are clear, because most close voters assume that every language works like English, and therefore completely misunderstood the OP's very simple question. I've edited the question to make the issue clear. Perhaps you could help with a reopen vote? [or a unilateral reopening, in this case?] It's a straightforward grammar issue. Not a matter of opinion at all!

Comment: Sarvesh, do you really mean what is said here after this *heavy editing*?

Comment: @Araucaria another good solution. Let this remain closed as you too believe this; and I ask the same question in a different way because I'm clear about what all happened here in comments and how exactly you took this question positively.

Comment: @Araucaria if I reopen the question and you undo your edit, it'll be again ambiguous. The problem is the 'depth' you see in this question, the OP seems to be completely unaware of! :)

Answer (score 16):

I believe I understand your concern because similar confusion arose at some point in my English study, too, due to a linguistic difference between my native tongue and English. Your language is perhaps like mine, Thai, where you answer to *the truth condition of the statement of the question* rather than *the truth itself*. For example, if you ask, in Thai, "aren't you going to school today?" and the answer is "yes," the answerer means they are *not* going to school. "Yes" here is "yes, (it is true that I am not going to school)," not "yes, (I'm going to school.)"

I think it helps if you think of English as somewhat simpler than that. In English, whether you answer "yes" or "no" *only* depends on *the reality* and has nothing to do with how the question is worded. Whether the question is "do you know?" or "don't you know?," "yes" and "no" still have the same meanings: in both cases, if you answer "yes,"  it means "you know," and if you answer "no," it means "you don't know."

Answering with plain "yes" or "no," however, may sound too flat and could sometimes be misunderstood, so it's safer to respond with a complete answer like "yes, I do." (meaning, you *know*) or "no, I don't" (meaning, you *don't know*) if you can't think of anything fancier like "no, I never knew," or "no, this is the first time I've heard about it!"

As stated by other Answerers, one thing to consider is that sometimes "don't you know?" is a rhetorical question, meaning the speaker doesn't actually expect an answer, so you don't have to answer them. You usually can guess from context whether it is an actual question or not.

Answer (score 4):

"Don't you know?" people ask such kind of question is because they though you should know. so your answer to this question is more likely to be negative. you should answer with the reason why you don't know him.

such as "No, I never heard about that."

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 common uses for this phrase - there is the 'slightly posh' "Don't you know" as an end-of-sentence, which is essentially just emphasis & not requiring an answer. Not common these days in speech but you'll see it in older books & films.

The main one is generally where you might have been expected to know something - so, often a rhetorical (or patronising) element to it, which is worth being alert to. It is perhaps worth observing that in more formal use, this expands to "do you not know" (or "did you not know") & NOT "do not you know" as you might have expected!

The usual forms of answer would be "No, I don't", or "Yes, I do" although there is quite likely to be some form of addition, the sharper "No, actually, I don't" or "No, could you tell me please?". If in doubt, keep it simple!

It is possible to use a simple "No" but I think it would be unusual in speech - mainly because of the subtle implications rather than a hard grammatical rule - and therefore the inflections would be important; so a rising pitch, as a question, would probably draw an explanation.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand the OP's question!! What he wants to know is whether to give an affirmative or negative response.

Comment: @Araucaria That rather depends on whether the speaker actually knows or does not know. This question is not some kind of bizarre logic trap in which "yes" and "no" evaluate to the same thing. Saying "yes" or "no" by themselves are ambiguous, but the "I do/don't" confirmation makes it unambiguous.

Comment: @CrazyEyesThe OP's question is not "What can I do to be understood" but "What would my reply mean if I said *Yes*". They state in their comments: *Can't it be answered with only Yes or No? Again similar question:)*

Comment: @CrazyEyes A one word reply is *not* ambiguous here for a native speaker :)

Answer (score 3):

Some of the confusion arises from the facts (a) that the premise behind the question is the opposite of the literal words of the question, and (b) that the question does not actually seek a literal answer.

"Don't you know?" is basically a rhetorical question.  The person asking that question actually assumes that you do in fact "know," and since it is assumed that you do in fact "know," no response is required.

However, when you actually do not "know" and wish to make that fact known, the correct one-word answer would be "No."

I think that the main reason for confusion arises from the fact that the question is asked in the negative and the concern is that a response of "No" is a second negative, which combined with the first negative would result in a positive.

However, double negatives do not arise in a two-party exchange.  The double negative that results in a positive statement occurs only when both negatives are articulated by the same party within a single statement.

*(Note:  Even though the correct one-word response would be “No,” most native speakers, whether they are the asker or the answerer, would prefer the more expanded response of “No, I don’t,” because for either party that short-cuts the need to mentally analyze the effect of the negative question and the negative response.)*

Comment: People with an Upper-Midwestern (American) accent often append "don'cha know?" to the ends of sentences.  They often mean it as a humorous statement of conventional wisdom, and do not expect a reply to the question.  In your words, it "is basically a rhetorical question."

Answer (score 3):

As usual it depends somewhat on the context, but the phrase "Don't you know?" is very often not so much a question as an expression of surprise, as in:

> Alice: I'm going to visit Bob in hospital this afternoon
>   Cathy: My Goodness, what happened to Bob?
>   Alice: Don't you know? He's had appendicitis

In which case an answer isn't really required. If Alice is still unsure if Cathy really doesn't know, she may pause for an answer before elaborating, in which case it would go

> Alice: I'm going to visit Bob in hospital this afternoon
>   Cathy: My Goodness, what happened to Bob?
>   Alice: Don't you know?
>   Cathy: No, I haven't heard anything
>   Alice: He's had appendicitis

I would not recommend a one word answer to this question, but whether you go for a simple yes/no or a longer sentence an affirmative "yes" says "I do know" and "no" says "I do not know". Given that the asker felt the need to ask, the answer will almost always be "no".

Answer (score 0):

Answering a negated question is tricky because “yes” and “no” can both be interpreted (in practice) as either agreeing or disagreeing with either the statement or the negation. So, you need to clarify:

- No, I don’t.
- No, I do.
- Yes, I don’t.
- Yes, I do.

And if you’re going to do that, you might as well leave off the “yes” or “no” since they don’t really add any value.

Comment: A: Don't you know? B: Yes, I don’t. - You wrote this is one of four possible answers. Is it so?