# How to agree with a negative statement: with "yes" or with "no"?

Tags: negation, subject-verb-agreement

This question here asks about answering negative **questions**:

- [How to answer a negative question in English?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71446/how-to-answer-a-negative-question-in-english)

I have a completely different question. I want to know:

- how do we agree or disagree with negative ***statements*** in English.

Example:

––This is not a duplicate question.

––Yes, it is a new one.

or

––This is not a duplicate question.

––No, it is a new one.

Comment: I do not know how to explain how my question is different other than how I stated it. Please read the title: This is NOT a duplicate because the first person is NOT asking a _question_ but is making a _negative statement_ with which the second person wants to agree.

Comment: I completely agree with your comment. This is not a dupe. Have voted to reopen.

Comment: Your question is now reopened! :)

Comment: I appreciate very much the edit and I learned something. (Even though I had rather expected the "duplicate question" issue to come up, I did not dare be that explicit and the closer I had thought I could come was to use the example as a hint.)

Answer (score 5):

The standard way is to clarify your answer by rephrasing the question rather than *only* saying "no" or "yes".

> A - This is not a duplicate question.
>   B - Yes, it is [a duplicate question].
>
> A - This is not a duplicate question.
>   B - No, it is not [a duplicate question].

Comment: @ Catija Actually, I should have stated my question the way I just edited it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @ Catija      I agree that this would clarify but I would like to know which of the two answers I gave would be properly understood---if at all, because, to compare, I asked the same question on French Language.     (http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18904/comment-exprimer-son-agr%C3%A9ment-avec-une-n%C3%A9gation-par-oui-ou-par-non)