# How to answer a negative question

Tags: questions

Can anyone tell me if an interrogative negative question is always answered in positive or can it also be answered in negative?

Comment: It's least confusing to answer with a statement, like "I did," if answering a question like *did you not eat?*

Comment: This question might also be helpful: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/88502/

Answer (score 1):

It can be answered in the positive or in the negative.

If you ask "Didn't you go there last week?", I could answer:

- Yes (I did), *or*
- No (I didn't).

If you ask "Aren't you hungry?", I could answer:

- Yes (I am), *or*
- No (I'm not).

If you ask "He wants to come with us, doesn't he?", I could answer:

- Yes (he does), *or*
- No (he doesn't).