# Do I Answer “Yes” or “No”

Tags: confusable

So In this job application there’s a statement “…Drug Free Environment. I am not a current user of illegal drugs, and I agree I will never work under the influence of drugs or alcohol.” This confuses me tremendously and I want to say that No, Im not a drug user and never have been. How should I answer?

Comment: Yes, [it is true that] I am not a current user of drugs. Is the statement "I am not a current user of drugs" true? yes. The correct answer is "yes"

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, the second half makes it clear that not using drugs should receive a "yes" answer.

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/233915/how-to-answer-a-negative-question/233920#233920

Comment: I think my previous comment may be a bit opaque. The question actually posed by the employment application is framed as an indicative statement. Moreover, half of it is negative, and half positive. This is a mess not of your making. I would not rely on “yes” or “no” answers because HR departments are usually staffed by people with IQ’s below their shoe sizes. Be explicit: “No, I don’t take drugs, and yes, I’ll gladly sign that agreement.” Anyone inept enough to draft that “question” cannot be trusted to interpret a bare “yes” or “no” answer.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, the question is ineptly phrased.

You want to agree with this statement, so  "True" or "Correct" could be used to indicate that this statement is true for you.  Or you could write "I agree".  If there is a checkbox you would tick it ✓

If there are two checkboxes for "yes" and "no", then you would tick the box marked "Yes".

<sub>It is *so* inept that it reminds me of the the Jim Crow questions that were used to prevent black people from voting - an unanswerable question to guarantee that anyone who answered it can be rejected at the prejudice of the tester.</sub>

Comment: It’s not Shakespeare, but how is it inept? :)

Comment: See Jeffs comment above..  It is highly uncertain how "yes" would be interpreted here.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that comment but I didn't think being asked to answer yes/no to a statement (rather than a direct question) was remotely "inept". And as far as I can tell both statements are negative ("am not …, will never …"). But the fact that this question was asked does of course mean that it was not clear to at least one applicant, which certainly is a failure on the prospective employer's part.