# mm/hm/um huh/okay - does not tell an opinion but just a sound saying that "ok, I am listening"?

Tags: connotations, responses

**Example 1**

> A: We don't need some employees at this company.

> B: mm/hm/um huh/okay.

Does this only mean that B is paying attention, like saying "Okay, I am listening"?

**Example 2**

> A: We don't need some employees at this company.

> B: I agree/Yes/right.

Does this mean that B is also thinking that they don't need some employees at the company?

Comment: "Okay" can mean either "just listening" or "I agree". Everything else you're correct about.

Comment: Your second example seems to be a duplicate of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71446/how-to-answer-a-negative-question-in-english.

Comment: "We don't need **any (more)** employees", to which B would reply "No (we don't)".

Comment: It depends on how they say it. You can say "okay" in a dubious way, where it means something like "I'm really not sure I agree but I won't argue", or you can say it in a super-positive way meaning "absolutely true". "Right" can mean "yes" or "stop there". "I agree" normally means what it says, but the rest depends on tone of voice.

Comment: This behavior is called [**backchanneling**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backchannel_(linguistics)), by the way.

Comment: Okay can be way of stalling a lunatic while you find an exit

Comment: Didn't people say or write 'mmmkay'?

Answer (score 0):

B isn't saying enough for someone reading the transcript to know exactly what they were thinking.

Generally "Yes", or "I agree" do mean that B's opinion is the same as A's  (but watch out for  "I agree but..."  or "Yes, and ..." which might be tactful ways of disagreeing!)  And sounds like "hmm" indicate thought, but not agreement. "Okay" could mean almost anything.

To understand what B is really thinking, we will have to wait to hear what they say next, or even better find out what they *do*. (Remember B can say "Yes" while thinking "No".)